# How can I increase the display size of desktop folders beyond the maximum 128x128?

Tags: icon, desktop

I want to increase the display size of desktop icons beyond the maximum 128x128. Is there a command I can use to do it?

(macOS Mojave)

Answer (score 0):

On Big Sur, the view options can select icons up to 512px square. I suspect the change was made in Catalina, so you may have to upgrade.

[image]

Mind you, even 128 is pretty large. Might you want to change the overall scaling of your display instead?